# Click function does not append HTML block using append() function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I'm trying to append the same code again on click. My 'education_wrap" class empty for now. Other than that I have just added in-line CSS for now.

```js
var max_fields = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper = $(".education_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button = $("#add_education"); //Add button ID
    
$(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var total_fields = wrapper[0].childNodes.length;
    if(total_fields < max_fields){
        $(wrapper).append('<p style="font-weight:bold;">Institute Name<span class="required">*</span></p><div class="item"><input type="text" id="institute" name="institute" placeholder="Institute Name" required/></div><p style="font-weight:bold;">Degree Name<span class="required">*</span></p><div class="item"><input type="text" id="degree" name="degreen" placeholder="Bachelor of Engineering in Software Engineering, etc." required/></div><p style="font-weight:bold;">From<span class="required">*</span></p><div class="item"><input type="date" id="from_date" name="from_date" value="2020-07-22" required/></div><p style="font-weight:bold;">To<span class="required">*</span></p><div class="item">                    <input type="date" id="to_date" name="to_date" value="2020-07-22" required/></div></div>'); //add input box
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <form><h3 style="font-weight: bold;">Education</h3>
        <div class="education_wrap">
        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Institute Name<span class="required">*</span></p>
          <div>                    
            <input type="text" id="institute" name="institute" placeholder="Institute Name" required/>
          </div>

        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Degree Name<span class="required">*</span></p>
          <div>                    
            <input type="text" id="degree" name="degreen" placeholder="Bachelor of Engineering in Software Engineering, etc." required/>
          </div>

        <p style="font-weight:bold;">From<span class="required">*</span></p>
          <div>                      
            <input type="date" id="from_date" name="from_date" value="2020-07-22" required/>
          </div>

        <p style="font-weight:bold;">To<span class="required">*</span></p>
          <div>                    
            <input type="date" id="to_date" name="to_date" value="2020-07-22" required/>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div style="margin-top:20px;">
          <button id="add_education">Add Another Education</button>
        </div></form>
```

Also, I cannot get my mind around how to submit multiple sets of information using POST method for  once. Please guide.

Comment: did you checked that for condition `if(total_fields < max_fields){`, also do not use submit button to append on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var max_fields = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper = $(".education_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button = $("#add_education"); //Add button ID

$(add_button).click(function(e) {
  var total_fields = wrapper[0].childNodes.length;
  alert(total_fields < max_fields);
  //if (total_fields < max_fields) { // this condition returns false that's why it creates issue
    $(wrapper).append('<p style="font-weight:bold;">Institute Name<span class="required">*</span></p><div class="item"><input type="text" id="institute" name="institute" placeholder="Institute Name" required/></div><p style="font-weight:bold;">Degree Name<span class="required">*</span></p><div class="item"><input type="text" id="degree" name="degreen" placeholder="Bachelor of Engineering in Software Engineering, etc." required/></div><p style="font-weight:bold;">From<span class="required">*</span></p><div class="item"><input type="date" id="from_date" name="from_date" value="2020-07-22" required/></div><p style="font-weight:bold;">To<span class="required">*</span></p><div class="item">                    <input type="date" id="to_date" name="to_date" value="2020-07-22" required/></div></div>'); //add input box
  //}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">Education</h3>
  <div class="education_wrap">
    <p style="font-weight:bold;">Institute Name<span class="required">*</span></p>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="institute" name="institute" placeholder="Institute Name" required/>
    </div>
    <p style="font-weight:bold;">Degree Name<span class="required">*</span></p>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="degree" name="degreen" placeholder="Bachelor of Engineering in Software Engineering, etc." required/>
    </div>
    <p style="font-weight:bold;">From<span class="required">*</span></p>
    <div>
      <input type="date" id="from_date" name="from_date" value="2020-07-22" required/>
    </div>
    <p style="font-weight:bold;">To<span class="required">*</span></p>
    <div>
      <input type="date" id="to_date" name="to_date" value="2020-07-22" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top:20px;">
    <button type="submit" id="add_education">Add Another Education</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note:- There is a slight mistake in your code. There is one if condition which returns a false value that's why a block of code is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

There is many issue in your Code, follow below things:

1 . `if(total_fields < max_fields){` Here your condition getting false, so no `append` process will begin

2 . use `type="button"` instead of `submit`

3 . use separate button for append `html` and for `submit` form

for **how to submit multiple sets of information using POST**

use input name as array like `<input type="date" id="from_date" name="from_date[]" value="2020-07-22" required/>`

use `classes` instead of `id` here because of repetition here `id="from_date"`